# Python manage for some continuous server process

Tags: python, server, process, connection, communication

I want to create some simple server app in Python. 
For now i have prototypes of 2 modules:

1: server module, that operates with database, which stores some orders to be done. It must start worker threads which make changes to DB and send results to module 2

2: listener module, thar listens external commands from users and sends results from module 1 to users.

I need to implement:

- Some Main module that starts and watch over server and listener modules, that must running all the time.
- methods to make connection between server and listener module, that they could operate together and be assured that all orders get completed.

I need some help with choosing right modules or tools to implement this. 
I watched at asyncio, but it could be not what i need.

Comment: So do it why are you posting this here.

Comment: Im new at python and asking for some tools or modules to start with that could help